# Entity framework recursive join

Tags: api, rest, entity-framework-core, hierarchy, recursive-query

I have two tables in sql, in the first table have a recursive data, the structure is like this:

```sql
Id | Name      | ParentId | NivelId
1  | Process1  | NULL     | 0
2  | Process2  | 1        | 1
3  | Process3  | 1        | 1
4  | Process4  | NULL     | 0
5  | Process5  | 4        | 1
```

My second table is a catalog of Nivel:

```sql
NivelId | Description
0       | Macroprocess
1       | Process
2       | Subprocess
```

I need an API that return the data as follows:

```json
[{
 Id: 1,
 Name: 'Process1',
 NivelId: 0,
 NivelName: 'Macroprocess',
 Subprocecss: [
 {
  Id: 2,
  Name: 'Process2',
  ParentId: 1
  NivelId: 1,
  NivelName: 'Process'  
 },
 {
  Id: 3,
  Name: 'Process3',
  ParentId: 1
  NivelId: 1,
  NivelName: 'Process'  
 }
 ]
},
...
]
```

I am using the following code with entity framework core 3.1:

My model

```
public class ProcessInventory
    {
        public ProcessInventory()
        {
            SubProcess = new HashSet<ProcessInventory>();
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public int NivelId { get; set; }
        public virtual ProcessInventory ParentProcess { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProcessInventory> SubProcess { get; set; }

    }

    public class ProcessInventoryDTO
    {
        public ProcessInventoryDTO()
        {
            Id = -1;
            ParentId = -1;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public int NivelId { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProcessInventory>>> GetInventory()
{
   var processFull = await _context.ProcessInventory
                .Include(x => x.SubProcess).ToListAsync();
   var process = processFull.Where(c => c.ParentProcess == null).ToList();
   return procesos;
}
```

The code is working, but I don't know how to join it to my catalog entity to take the name of the nivel. Please your help.

Comment: Nothing special here, just add and use a regular reference navigation property to your `ProcessInventory` class, something like `public virtual Nivel Nivel { get; set; }`. And make sure to `Include` it in the query result.

Comment: Thanks it works